# How to get form's dynamically created image inside controller action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an `<img>` in a form dynamically using JQuery and want to save this dynamically added image upon form submission.

The issue is that I'm not sure how to receive/read this image in the controller's action to save. I tried adding a `Name` attribute in `<img>` using the below code.

```
 $("form").append("<img  name="+ "UPIMG" + "  src=" + event.target.result + " />");
```

On the server side (in action), I tried to read dynamically created `<img>` using below code, but it is always null.

```
var tempImg = Request.Form["UPIMG"]
```

**Note:** I can see new images appearing in page and new tag added inside form.

Can you please help me figure out how to read and save this image on the server?

Answer (score 1):

`img` is not an HTML form element - it does not participate in the form submittal process.

You will need to get the image bytes into an element that does participate - like `input`

```
<input type='hidden' />
```

Comment: thanks. I am able to access a sort of encrypted string in action. I need to save images in database. Should I store it as it is ? Or Should remove its headers like data:image/jpge;base64 ? Below is sample of such a string.
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8KCwkMEQ8SEhEPERATFhwXExQaFRARGCEYGhwdHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7